# Objects are transparent from certain angles

Tags: modeling, camera, transparency

So i've been editing a few models and at random times the model would become see through depending on the angle i was at. Both in Edit and Object mode.

If i go to Compositing it stops.

For example if i look head on at a character head i can see the inside o fthe back of the head, the front appears to be in wireframe mode.

Then if i rotate the camera to be at the back of the head, i can see the inside of the face.

I think i hit a shortcut but i'm not sure

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or a blend file?

Comment: So depending on what angle i look at the face, i can only see the other end of it

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/308033125479350275/330139038738677760/Untitled.png

Comment: It could also be a viewport camera clipping issue, particularly if your model is very small/large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description of your situation, you might have inverted the normal of your mesh object.

Go into mesh edit mode.  Select the entire head/or everything, go to mesh menu, select Normals option, select Recalculate Outside option.

Answer (score 0):

I had another issue, under Texture Settings, there is Blend Mode option, transparency effect disappeared when I changed it to Opaque (it was Alpha Blend):

[image]